# converting column-structured arrays into rows

Tags: typescript

I'm sorry for asking but every time when I need to do something like this I get so confused.
Every time I get stuck with multiple loops and the final decision that I make looks scary.

Let's say you got an object like this one:

```
export interface Data {
    id: number;
    type: string;
}
```

and array of that object:

```
let data: Data[] = [
     { id: 1, type: 'one' },
     { id: 2, type: 'two' }
];
```

what is the easiest/safe way to create an array like this one:

```
arrdata = [
   [1, 2],
   ['one', 'two']
];
```

The idea is similar to converting column-structured data into rows:

```
1,2
1,2
1,2

1,1,1
2,2,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Create array of empty arrays, which number is equal to key count.
Then for each object in `data` we go through each `key` and push it into corresponding array.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, type: "one" },
  { id: 2, type: "two" },
  { id: 3, type: "three" }
];

const keys = Object.keys(data[0]).sort();
const arrData = new Array(keys.length).fill(0).map((_) => []);
data.forEach((d) => keys.forEach((k, i) => arrData[i].push(d[k])));

console.log(arrData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.reduce` like this

```js
let data = [
     { id: 1, type: 'one' },
     { id: 2, type: 'two' }
];

const initialData = [[],[]]

const newData = data.reduce((acc, { id, type }) => {
  acc[0].push(id);
  acc[1].push(type);
  return acc;
}, initialData)

console.log(newData)
```